# How to set Android Studio path in Worklight Studio on Mac

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to use Android Studio with Worklight Studio. WL Studio tells me to specify location of Android Studio in Eclipse->Preferences->Worklight.

When I open the dialoag and select Browse, I am unable to select the Android Studio entry in Applications folder, because it is greyed out. Entering manually /Applications/Android Studio does not help either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the location meaning the directory containing "Android Studio.app", if you have "Android Studio.app" located in "/Applications" directory then that's the directory path you need to select of enter the path in the input box.

[image]

This is applicable also to Windows and Linux.

I agree with you that the documentation could be improve to better clarify that is a directory path what's the input value for "Android Studio Location" in this case location means "Folder"